# How to send a request to another controller in Laravel using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, guzzle

I am trying to send a POST request using Guzzle to a route defined in my `routes/web.php` from a model. Both the model and the controller are defined in the same Laravel application. The controller action linked to the route returns a JSON response and works fine when called from javascript using Ajax. However, when I try to do this using Guzzle, I have the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (419)
Client error: `POST https://dev.application.com/login` resulted in a `419 unknown status` response
```

When searching for a solution, I read that it may be caused by a missing csrf token, so I added it to my reuqest, but I still get the same error.

Here's the model code that uses Guzzle to send the request:

```php
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post(APPLICATION_URL.'login', [
    'headers' => [
        'X-CSRF-Token' => csrf_token()
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'socialNetwork' => 'L',
        'id_token' => $id
    ],
]);
```

`APPLICATION_URL` is simply the base URL of the application, starting with `https://`.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't send requests internally in your app, forward the call by dispatching post requests to routes instead

This method seems faster than using an HTTP client library like Guzzle

Your code should look something like this

```php
$request = Request::create(APPLICATION_URL . 'login', 'POST', [
        'socialNetwork' => 'L',
        'id_token' => $id
    ]);
$request->headers->set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf_token());
$response = app()->handle($request);
$response = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
```

## Update

You have to manually handle the response from internally dispatched routes, here's an example to get started

`web.php`

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $request = Request::create('/test', 'POST', ['var' => 'bar']);
    $request->headers->set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf_token());
    $response = app()->handle($request);
    $responseContent = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    return $responseContent;
});

Route::post('test', function () {
    $upperCaseVar = strtoupper(request()->var);
    return response(['foo' => $upperCaseVar]);
});
```

Access `/` route by `GET` request and get response from `/test` as if it's `POST` request
`Result`

```
{
   "foo": "BAR"
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `Route::dispatch` doesn't seem to exist, is the function in Illuminate\Routing\Route?

Comment: No, it's in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route`

Comment: Your solution seems to work, except for the post data; It seems to be ignored in the target controller action. `$request->has('socialNetwork')` returns false.

Comment: You have to handle the response manually, I updated my answer